# Case sensitiveness issue when calling an external DLL in Fortran and compiling with gfortran

Tags: dll, fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to call a DLL from a Fortran code compiled with gfortran. I'm importing *DISCON_32.dll* with:

```
!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLIMPORT :: DISCON
```

and compiling with:

```
mingw32-gfortran "DISCON_32.dll" -cpp -ffree-line-length-none -fno-automatic -Wall -fdefault-real-8 -fno-underscoring -static BladedDLLInterface.o -o "my_program"
```

I get the error:

```
BladedDLLInterface.o:BladedDLLInterface.f90(.text+0x6cd): undefined reference to 'discon'
```

Note that entry point *"discon"* is here called as lowercase. When looking into the DLL with Dependency Walker, entry point is *"DISCON"* (uppercase).

I cannot change the case of the DLL. Is there a way to tell my Fortran code to look for "DISCON" entry point instead of "discon"?

*(My extended googling of the question did not get me closer to a solution)*

Comment: With "alias", are you refering to the similar construction with other compiler such as !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLIMPORT, DECORATE, ALIAS:'DISCON' :: DISCON I fear it is not the case with gfortran (not sure) and I could not find a flag to change this behavior to at least all uppercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 ways to do this: let's make an example DLL and Fortran main to demonstrate the problem.

```
! dll1.f90
! gfortran dll1.f90 -shared -odll1.dll -Wl,--out-implib,libdll1.a
module not_used
   use ISO_C_BINDING
   implicit none
   contains
      function F(x) bind(C,name='F')
!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: F
         real(C_DOUBLE) F
         real(C_DOUBLE), intent(in) ::x
         F = x**2
      end function F
end module not_used
```

The command line use to build dll1.dll is shown in the comments.
Now we have a Fortran main:

```
! main1.f90
! fails:
! gfortran main1.f90 dll1.dll -omain1
! gfortran main1.f90 -L. -ldll1 -omain1
! works:
! gfortran main1.f90 dll1.dll -L. -ldll2 -omain1
! gfortran main1.f90 -L. -ldll1 -ldll2 -omain1
module mod1
   implicit none
   interface
      function F(x)
         import
         implicit none
!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLIMPORT :: F
         double precision F
         double precision, intent(in) :: x
      end function F
   end interface
end module mod1

program main1
   use mod1
   implicit none
   double precision x, y
   x = 13
   y = f(x)
   write(*,*) y
end program main1
```

The first two gfortran commands shown above fail to build main1.exe. The second two work, but we need a libdll2.a file, and we can create it with dlltool.exe. We start with dll2.def

```
; dlltool -z dll2.def --export-all-symbol dll1.dll
; dlltool -d dll2.def -l libdll2.a
LIBRARY dll1.dll
EXPORTS
    f = F
```

The first comment line above shows how to dlltool.exe to create a starting point for dll2.def. The output is not very useful in our case, so mostly we used a text editor to modify the starting point. The dll2.def file will create a libdll2.a file that is usefule for linking with dll1.dll, thus the LIBRARY line above. The symbol that got exported was 'F', but gfortran is going to look for 'f', so we rename it in the exports section.
Then we use dlltool.exe to create libdll2.a via the second comment line above. Having a libdll2.a means we can compile main1.f90 according to the comments in lines 6 or 7.
The second method uses a binding name for the function. This requires the function to be interoperable, but if it isn't then you probably couldn't invoke it in any simple way given that it probably wasn't compiled by gfortran. Here we don't need an extra dll2.lib, just a different declaration of the function in main2.f90:

```
! main2.f90
! gfortran main2.f90 dll1.dll -omain2
! gfortran main2.f90 -L. -ldll1 -omain2
module mod2
   use ISO_C_BINDING
   implicit none
   interface
      function F(x) bind(C,name='F')
         import
         implicit none
!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLIMPORT :: F
         real(C_DOUBLE) F
         real(C_DOUBLE), intent(in) :: x
      end function F
   end interface
end module mod2

program main2
   use mod2
   implicit none
   double precision x, y
   x = 13
   y = f(x)
   write(*,*) y
end program main2
```

This compiles with either of the gfortran commands given in the comments.
Finally you could use dynamic linking as in main3.f90:

```
! main3.f90
! gfortran main3.f90 dll1.dll -omain3
! gfortran main3.f90 -L. -ldll1 -omain3
module mod3
   use ISO_C_BINDING
   use ISO_C_BINDING, HANDLE => C_INTPTR_T
   use ISO_C_BINDING, C_INTPTR_T => C_INTPTR_T
   implicit none
   abstract interface
      function F(x) bind(C)
         import
         implicit none
         real(C_DOUBLE) F
         real(C_DOUBLE), intent(in) :: x
      end function F
   end interface
   interface
      function LoadLibrary(lpFileName) bind(C,name='LoadLibraryA')
         import
         implicit none
!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL :: LoadLibrary
         integer(HANDLE) :: LoadLibrary
         character(kind=C_CHAR) lpFIleName(*)
      end function LoadLibrary
      function GetProcAddress(hModule,lpProcName) bind(C,name='GetProcAddress')
         import
         implicit none
!GCC$ ATTRIBUTES STDCALL :: GetProcAddress
         type(C_FUNPTR) GetProcAddress
         integer(HANDLE), value :: hModule
         character(kind=C_CHAR) lpProcName(*)
      end function GetProcAddress
   end interface
end module mod3

program main3
   use mod3, F1 => F
   implicit none
   double precision x, y
   type(C_FUNPTR) ptr
   procedure(F1), pointer :: F
   integer(HANDLE) hModule
   hModule = LoadLibrary('dll1.dll'//C_NULL_CHAR)
   ptr = GetProcAddress(hModule,'F'//C_NULL_CHAR)
   call C_F_PROCPOINTER(ptr,F)
   x = 13
   y = f(x)
   write(*,*) y
end program main3
```

Either of the gfortran commands in the comments successfully builds main3.exe.

**Note**: on retesting, the main2.f90 and main3.f90 methods worked, but for some reason the method with main1.f90 and dll2.def no longer works, failing at runtime because it's trying to find the symbol 'f' in main1.exe rather than dll1.dll. Can't figure out why at this point.

**EDIT**: Well, I found a way to make the first approach work with the dll1.dll created above and the main1.f90 as it is, but I don't really [like](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V2hlQkVJZhE) it so I'll wait a few days to see if someone else comes up with a more palatable solution. If, after that time, this hasn't happened and someone is still interested, he should remind me and I may post what I came up with.

Comment: Line 2 of dll1.f90, lines 3, 4 6, and 7 of main1.f90m lines 1 and, more usefully, 2 of dll2.def, lines 2 and 3 of main2.f90, and lines 2 and 3 of main3.f90. Are those not visible in your browser?

Comment: OK, in the comments of the source file, I can see them now.

Comment: main2 method seems to work for me :-)  _("seem" because I fall into some other issues compiling with gfortran that do not exist with IVF)_